# Match column names with records in text file Using UFT/QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have this table of info in text file:

```
CurrentOdometerReading PreviousOdometerReading GallonsOfGas GasPrice  MPG     TotalCost 
500                    200                     15           2.55      20      $38.25
600                    350                     18           2.55      13.89   $45.90
700                    510                     17           2.55      11.18   $43.35 
800                    443                     9            2.55      39.67   $22.95 
950                    801                     8            2.55      18.63   $20.40 
10000                  8043                    99           2.55      19.77   $252.45 
11000                  5004                    150          2.55      39.97   $382.50
```

The first line actually contains the column names.The next lines represent the data matching to the column name. I am having really hard time to print(loop) this data in below manner in UFT/QTP:

- CurrentOdometerReading = 500
- PreviousOdometerReading = 200
- Gallons = 15
- GasPrice = 2.55
- MPG = 20
- TotalCost = 38.25

If anyone had similar experience, I would REALLY appreciate your opinions. 
So far I wrote this:

```
Set Fso=createobject ("scripting.filesystemobject")

set txtfile=fso.OpenTextFile filepath

var1=txtfile.ReadAll 

var1=split(var1,vblf)
numarray= ubound(var1)
 For i = 0 To numarray

content=split(var1(i)," ")
numlinearr=ubound(content)

print content(i)

'For Iterator = 1 To numlinearr
'bol=split(content(Iterator)," ")
'print content(i)&" = "& bol(Iterator)

'Next
next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a nice beginning. Though what you miss is an specific array for your data definition. And it's better not to keep the same variable name for different uses(as you do with Var1)

Something like :

```
fileFull = txtFile.ReadAll
fileLines = Split(fileFull, vblf)
fileDataNames = Split(fileLines(0), " ")
numArray = UBound(fileLines)
numData = UBound(fileDataNames)

For LineNumber = 1 To numArray
    content = ""
    localDatas = Split(fileLines, " ")
    For dataNumber = 0 to numData
        content = content & fileDataNames(dataNumber) & " = " & localDatas(dataNumber)
    Next
    Print content
Next
```

The base idea is to store the first line elsewhere, as you're going to use it several times. That's why the first loop starts from 1, and not from 0(the base for any tabled created by the split function) : the line zero is something else.

Comment: thanks a lot! :) that was very explanatory. As you see in my code, I had the foggy logic and some ideas but i couldnt put them together. THANK YOU! and you are right about the variable names too))

Comment: btw, I put localDatas=Split(fileLines(LineNumber), " ") since "fileLines" is an array

Comment: ah, yes, I had missed that. Good spot.